# Are there any packages or configuration snippets for better whitespace traversal?

Tags: region, whitespace, point

Whitespace traversal in Emacs is atrocious. By "traversal" I mean:

- Moving the point with `C-<direction>`
- Expanding a selection (with either a package or region mark)
- Deleting with `C-` or `M-` `backspace` or `delete`

It trips over punctuation, deletes the next word when deleting whitespace ahead of point, and leaps from paragraph to space to maybe the next paragraph, if there aren't an odd number of spaces, and Mercury is not in retrograde.

I *believe* (without having inspected the related code) that the core issue is the way Emacs handles the traversal of the point over whitespace (since marking regions, deleting, and traversing are so related).

Has anyone taken a wrench to this and produced an improved configuration or package?

In order to keep this question actionable, I am specifically looking for a configuration that allows the user to delete usually contiguous chunks of whitespace, text, or a mix of those efficiently and accurately, without an unreasonable amount of new commands and shortcuts. You know, like those "other" text editors do.

Comment: Define "better". And better than what? Please *specify* the behavior you are looking for. Otherwise, this risks being closed as primarily opinion-based (not to mention unclear/hand-waving). It also sound too broad, asking about movement, region expansion, and deletion.

Comment: Avy and zap-to-char make things pretty efficient.  There's also an avy version of zap-to-char.

Comment: I'm not a UX designer; I can't tell you what I want the behavior to be. All I can tell you is what is wrong. Just like a patient in an examination room, if I knew what the solution was I wouldn't be there. Given that the behavior of Emacs around whitespace traversal is different (hungrier? vaguer?) than most other text editors, and that Emacs is so customizable, it seems all the more useful to ask about the problem wholistically, rather than asserting that specific subjective symptoms (and cures) sum up the whole issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking.  What concrete task are you trying to achieve?  Is there some other editor whose behavior you'd like to emulate?

Comment: @AaronHarris is "delete usually contiguous chunks of whitespace, text, or a mix of those efficiently and accurately, without an unreasonable amount of new commands and shortcuts" unclear?

Comment: There are two commands in Emacs that allow you to remove whitespace around point. M-SPC replaces whitespace with a single space, and M-\ just deletes it. These commands might be enough for you.